# BIMI Validation failure

Tags: dns, email, dmarc, bimi

I have set up a BIMI record for my business, but when checking with 'https://www.mailkit.com/resources/bimi-inspector' I am told that my BIMI record is valid:

```
default._bimi.domain.co.uk 3600 IN TXT "v=BIMI1;l=https://domain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Logo.svg;"
```

The inspector flags up 2 errors:

- SVG contains disallowed references - I have no idea what this means or how to check/remove/change these references. IT doesn't give an indication as to what the references are either.
- Insufficient DMARC Policy for BIMI

My Dmarc policy is:

```
v=DMARC1; p=reject; pct=1; sp=none; fo=1; ri=3600; 
rua=mailto:domain@rua.agari.com,mailto:office@domain.co.uk, mailto:yvouslgn@ag.dmarcian.eu; 
ruf=mailto:domaink@ruf.agari.com,mailto:office@domain.co.uk
```

Any advice as to what might be wrong would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

On a side note in regards to validation failures:

I've done some extensive testing on urls that contain query strings such as `?color=000` and they are returning as failed on nearly half of the validators out there including **mxtoolbox**.

This is just a weakness in their parsers that don't understand a common case of a *perfectly valid url*, so to combat this incompetence, I made sure to simplify the url structure for these kinds of things and *remove any query strings* because I'd rather just dumb it down than to risk edge case behavior.

Also, make sure to confirm your **svg** is actually an **svg**, it has become quite common for many of these online image conversion tools to make the conversion by simply base64 encoding the png content and sticking it into the svg metadata instead of actually tracing it and providing the proper vector values.

Such cheap practices theses days, should be banned.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wish this was the issue I was facing, but unfortunately not :-( lol. My URLs contain no Query Strings and my Graphic is an SVG, which I designed myself lol. Its getting frustrating

Answer (score 1):

**SVG contains disallowed references**
You can download on Agari's own BIMI logo, check file content and make sure that your one also looks similar -> 
https://def0a2r1nm3zw.cloudfront.net/bimi_asset_1f1282c553248c0518e4652ee2bebcf0.svg

**Insufficient DMARC Policy for BIMI**
change "p=reject; pct=1; sp=none" to "p=reject". applying "reject" to 1% is not enough for protection

Comment: Thank you for your answer. the file content to check - Would that be checking the path?

Comment: Can you tell domain name or path ?

Comment: Thank you zonder, I managed to solve the problem by saving my SVG as an optimized SVG which allowed me to remove the meta data